# How can I define multiple schemas on a postgresql docker-compose instance?

Tags: postgresql

I have a dockerized environment that I am working on, which instantiates a postgres DB instance, with a public schema out of the box. All good here.
But now, I want to create an extra schema with some new tables in it, and I'm not sure how/if I can achieve this.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

My docker-compose postgres definition, currently looks like this:

```
 mw-db:
    image: postgres:14.4
    container_name: mw-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mw
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      mw-network:
        aliases:
          - mw-db
      default: {}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding "initialization scripts", as explained in the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) for the image:

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

So, you can create a folder, e.g. `/data/initdb`, put your sql-scripts for creating schemas et al there, map this to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in container, and be done:

```
mw-db:
    image: postgres:14.4
    container_name: mw-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mw
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      mw-network:
        aliases:
          - mw-db
      default: {}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - /data/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```